# cocoa - draw image in NSView

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, nsview, nsimage

I'm having difficulties understanding why the below code doesn't work, what I want to achieve is an image being displayed in the top left corner of a NSView, but nothing is showing...

```
NSImage *map0 = [NSImage imageNamed:@"map0.png"];
NSRect rect = NSMakeRect(0, 0, 400, 400);
[map0 drawInRect:rect fromRect:NSZeroRect operation:NSCompositeSourceAtop fraction:1.0f];
[map drawRect:rect];
```

**EDIT:**

`map` is the NSView into which I would like to draw the image into

Comment: Can you explain that last line a bit more? What is the `map` variable in this context, and why does it need to draw the same rect that you make for your image?

Comment: sorry, I forgot to say that, map is the NSView...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You never call `drawRect:` directly. This routine has various pre-conditions that are provided by Cocoa, such as the creation of a `CGContextRef`. You implement `drawRect:`. Cocoa calls it.

Your `drawInRect:fromRect:operation:fraction:` call should be put into the `drawRect:` of `map`, which should be a subclass of `NSView`. This specific problem is usually better solved with an `NSImageView` rather than a custom `NSView`, but if the drawing is more complex, then a custom `NSView` is appropriate.

Comment: What would you recommend for the following situation: what I would like to achieve is a map, and I have 6 images which together create a map of the world this should then be somehow draggable and zoomable, so imagine it a bit like google maps... NSView or NSImageView?

Comment: To make something much larger than the screen drag and zoom with good performance, you often want CATiledLayer. But if this is your first app, you may want to start with something simpler, and just put 6 imageviews in a scrollview. For something only 6x the size of the screen, it may be fast enough.

Comment: How did you guess this was my first app? :P anyway the scroll view idea is good it sound simpler, I'll then try to go to a CATiledLayer. Thanks for your help :)